# Aurelia Push State App Reload on Login and Logout

Tags: pushstate, aurelia, aurelia-auth

When configuring Push State with Aurelia and Visual Studio, I am getting an odd behavior where after I select login my entire app reloads instead of the router just pushing to the homepage. This also happens when I logout, I get to the login screen and it refreshes the entire app. I am using Aurelia Auth. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had the exact same issue some time ago and this was one of the reasons I switched back to `pushState = false` (but my infos may be helpful for you).

Anyways, the following issue describes what I was facing: https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth/issues/55

The problem is, internally the plugin sets href:

Login - https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth/blob/master/src/authentication.js#L95-L99

```
if (this.config.loginRedirect && !redirect) {
  window.location.href = this.getLoginRedirect();
} else if (redirect && isString(redirect)) {
  window.location.href = window.encodeURI(redirect);
}
```

Logout - https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth/blob/master/src/authentication.js#L139-L143

```
if (this.config.logoutRedirect && !redirect) {
  window.location.href = this.config.logoutRedirect;
} else if (isString(redirect)) {
  window.location.href = redirect;
}
```

What you need to do is avoid both conditions, i.e. set `loginRedirect` and `logoutRedirect` to the empty string (`''`). Then, do the navigation on your own via Aurelias router as I did in my example from the GH issue:

```
return this.auth.login(userInfo)
  .then(response => {
    console.log('You signed in successfully.');
    this.router.navigate('/contents');
  })
```

Of course, do the same router navigation on your logout method.

Comment: Yes this sounds exactly like the same issue. It seems odd though that we would have to hack it up to make it work properly. I kept thinking its the server side setup with the route mapping vs Aurelia's router. It doesn't seem like your issue was even answered here https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth/issues/55

Comment: Thanks for answering.